# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady error in my django app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add the django-ads module to my web app but i have few problems.

to install django ads I need to add code in my settings.py but there is the module gettext which is needed and there is some "_" who generate me error. so I imported the following things in my settings.py.

```
from ads.conf import gettext  
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

after that when I try to runserver that's show me this error :

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.

don't know how to fix that, I've seen some post about de wsgi.py files but it's good.

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yufindRe.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

ads config in settings.py

```
#ads config

ADS_GOOGLE_ADSENSE_CLIENT = None  # 'ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

ADS_ZONES = {
    'header': {
        'name': gettext('Header'),
        'ad_size': {
            'xs': '720x150',
            'sm': '800x90',
            'md': '800x90',
            'lg': '800x90',
            'xl': '800x90'
        },
        'google_adsense_slot': None,  # 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'google_adsense_format': None,  # 'auto'
    },
    'content': {
        'name': gettext('Content'),
        'ad_size': {
            'xs': '720x150',
            'sm': '800x90',
            'md': '800x90',
            'lg': '800x90',
            'xl': '800x90'
        },
        'google_adsense_slot': None,  # 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'google_adsense_format': None,  # 'auto'
    },
    'sidebar': {
        'name': gettext('Sidebar'),
        'ad_size': {
            'xs': '720x150',
            'sm': '800x90',
            'md': '800x90',
            'lg': '800x90',
            'xl': '800x90'
        }
    }
}

ADS_DEFAULT_AD_SIZE = '720x150'

ADS_DEVICES = (
    ('xs', _('Extra small devices')),
    ('sm', _('Small devices')),
    ('md', _('Medium devices (Tablets)')),
    ('lg', _('Large devices (Desktops)')),
    ('xl', _('Extra large devices (Large Desktops)')),
)

ADS_VIEWPORTS = {
    'xs': 'd-block img-fluid d-sm-none',
    'sm': 'd-none img-fluid d-sm-block d-md-none',
    'md': 'd-none img-fluid d-md-block d-lg-none',
    'lg': 'd-none img-fluid d-lg-block d-xl-none',
    'xl': 'd-none img-fluid d-xl-block',
}
```

Comment: From @Abdul Aziz Barkat: you can use the lazy versions in the setting also so gettext_lazy can be used (but not gettext as the OP tries). Generally the problem is if you try this in the settings, etc. what language is the function supposed to translate this to? So it is better to use the lazy function so it get's evaluated when needed on the basis of the request.

Comment: @acw why did you delete your answer though? Just a small edit and it would have been perfect, no need to delete answers when you can edit and give a better one :)

Comment: Ah the answer is not a very good one in retrospect considering all that needs to be done is use the lazy version in the settings file (if I'm getting that correct) :) I like small edits when they are improvements not complete re-done stuff. The stage is all yours!

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'm  gonna try to use gettext lazy but i don't understand exactly how to use it. did i need to replace all the "gettext" by "gettext_lazy" in my settings .py ? or did i just need to import it at the top of my settings.py file ? maybe need i to do the two things.  i made an update of my post just above to show you exactly where it is used.

Comment: it's okay i needed only to add _lazy juste after gettext like this : from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _  it work fine thank you for help :)